# how to achieve Tableau from SQL statement

Tags: tableau-api

Please can anyone help out on how to achieve sql statement in tableau. I have a table in Tableau that contains `ID    name    smkoes    SmokeCessRef    ward` etc as the dimension in tableau. In SQL i query the table as follows:

```
SELECT
    count(Distinct ID) as TotSmokeExcl
FROM IP
WHERE
    (Smokes in ('Yes') and SmokeCessRef in ('No'))
    OR
    (Smokes in ('Yes') and SmokeCessRef in ('No') and [Disch/LastWard] in ('Camp','House'))
```

How can i do this in tableau. or what process do i need to do to achieve this in Tableau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a calculated field with similar logic to that which you have in SQL.

```
([Smokes] = 'Yes' AND [SmokeCessRef] = 'No') OR
([Smokes] = 'Yes' AND [SmokeCessRef] = 'No' AND ([Disch/LastWard] = 'Camp' OR [Disch/LastWard] = 'House'))
```

Then put the calculated field in the filter card and set it to 'True'.

As an aside, your logic doesn't completely make sense. For instance, you are going to return all `(Smokes in ('Yes') and SmokeCessRef in ('No'))`, so the second part `(Smokes in ('Yes') and SmokeCessRef in ('No') and [Disch/LastWard] in ('Camp','House'))` is useless.